# Openpyxl remove pivot table fields

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table, openpyxl

I am using trying to export using openpyxl and the new pivot table functionality.

I currently have a workbook with two sheets (RawData and Pivot)
I load in the workbook, put data into raw data, close and export.

The Pivot table automatically updates the data when i open the file, however it shows the PivotTable fields / editing options on the right side bar.  Does anyone know how to remove this?

Preferably I would like a solution using openpyxl

```
wb = load_workbook(filename=template_file_path)

wb.remove_sheet(wb["RawData"])
ws = wb.create_sheet("RawData")
ws = wb["RawData"]

# ws.title = "RawData"
# #Add Headers
ws.append(data['headers'][1:])
# #Add raw data
for row in data['data']:
    ws.append(row[1:])




#File settings
file_name = str(template_file_path).replace(' ', '_') + "_export.xlsx"
response = HttpResponse(save_virtual_workbook(wb), content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename= "{0}"'.format(file_name)
return response
```

Answer (score 1):

After the first line you can add

```
ws_pivot = wb["Pivot"]
pivot = ws_pivot._pivots[0] 
pivot.disableFieldList = True
```

to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the pivot tables from a worksheet by setting the collection to an empty list: `ws._pivots = []`

Comment: I do not want to remove the pivot table.  I want to remove the Pivot table fields / pivot table editor on the right margin. 
Here is an example of what i want to remove: https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/b46252fd-038d-4875-848c-b8b6c69fb076.jpg It pops up every time I run code and open the excel file.  I do not have it open in my template